# Roslyn API documentation

Tags: .net, roslyn

I've developing with the Roslyn CTP, and I'm using the walkthroughs on MSDN and other code samples people have posted to learn.

However, I can't find any documentation that explains the various classes and methods that are part of the API.

I understand that the API is still in development, but is there a source that explains the API from a high level? I'm looking for documentation like you would normally find in MSDN for the .NET classes.

Other than the code samples, I'm left guessing what some of the classes and methods are designed for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find Roslyn reference documentation at http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/ .
It's automatically generated from the latest Roslyn source code, in MSDN like format. It's preliminary documentation of course.

Comment: @ROMANIA Do you expect them to post the entire documentation for roslyn? That's ridiculous

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for are [the draft API docs posted on MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/645ac1ef-d21b-40bf-8324-fefe0bd8c6f8).

**EDIT:** Now that Roslyn is hosted on CodePlex, its documentation is at https://roslyn.codeplex.com/documentation.

Comment: The links on the MSDN page are broken now.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I have added a new link. But the new docs don't seem to be as detailed as the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is official [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) from Microsoft.

The link provides documentation to the complete Roslyn compiler stack including,but not restricted to:

1. [KeyConcepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769#Toc306015672) - [Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769#Toc306015671),[Semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769#Toc306015686) and Services
2. [Code Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27745)